# how to use xorg-x11 X server on linux and windows?

Tags: linux, unix, amazon-ec2, x11, x11-forwarding

I am really stuck here.
I want to install and use xorg-x11 linux utility Which i am suggested to use to export UI from EC2 to my local machine.
I have installed "xorg-x11-apps.x86_64" on my ec2 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally on the remote site you only need the X11 libraries, not the full blown server. On your local machine you install a X11 server though. I recommend using Cygwin and use the X.org server it ships. Then you do

```
YOURWINDOWSMACHINE ~ > ssh -X USER@ec2-instance-address

EC2-INSTANCE ~ > some_program_using_X11
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you install cygwin on your local machine with X, you should be able to export the display and run the remote X application. If you're using something like ssh, have a look at its flags (-x or -X if memory serves)